# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename') in multer

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, multer

I have a very similar problem with respect to this fellow community contributor. How do i produce multer error message in my postman I followed through the comments made by other users and it was successful! However, when i tried to post a image that is a jpg formatted image( which i managed to do before the editing), it now fails and state that TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined.

> // multer.js file
>
> *successfully setup multer*

```
 **please tell me why this error comes on my code and give me a solution**



const multer = require('multer');
    
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      fileSize: 1024*1024*2,
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
      }
    
    })
    
    const filter = function (req, file, cb) {
      if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(new Error('unsupported files'), false)
      }
    }
    
    var upload = multer({
      storage: storage, 
      limits: {
          fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
      },
      fileFilter : filter
    });
    
    module.exports = upload;
```

> ```
> //controller.js file
> //create function
>
> here's my logic to create a new user
> ```

```
exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.body) {
            res.status(400).send({ message: "content cannot be empty !!" })
            return
        }
        let data = { name: req.body.name, description: req.body.description, brand_url: 
        req.body.brand_url, image_file: req.body.file.filename }; getting error here
        let sql = "INSERT INTO influencer SET ?";
        db.query(sql, data, (err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('data inserted succesfully')
            res.redirect('/admin');
        });
    }
```

> ```
> //api.js file
> //post API
> ```

```
router.post('/api/create', upload.single('image') ,controller.create) //when I am 
sending file its throw back error undefined filename
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure you have added enctype="multipart/form-data"

   ```
    <form action="/api/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   ```
2. I have tested the codes & found the problem.

   ```
    exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "content cannot be empty !!" })
        return
    }
    let data = { 
      name: req.body.name, 
      description: req.body.description, 
      brand_url: req.body.brand_url, 
      image_file: req.file.filename 
    }; // Remove "body", I have tested, it works well.

    let sql = "INSERT INTO influencer SET ?";
    db.query(sql, data, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('data inserted succesfully')
        res.redirect('/admin');
    });
   ```

   }